# Enforcing one-to-one matching of sass and css files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, jammit

I'm using Jammit to package assets and Sass to generate stylesheets in a Rails 3 app.  There are around 35 stylesheets for different site components and all are individually listed in our Jammit config.  I would like to get to something based more on convention, ie:

```
stylesheets:
  common:
    - public/stylesheets/application.css
    - public/stylesheets/components/*.css
    - public/stylesheets/pages/*.css
```

The only hurdle I am running into is that I can't find a way to enforce a one-to-one mapping between sass files and css files.  The above approach would remove the need to mess with the Jammit config and would automatically add new css files to the site, but if I were to remove a sass file the CSS file would still exist and would still be in our common package.  CSS files are ignored in the working tree.  Any way to tell Sass to remove CSS files with no template or do I have to add our CSS files to the repo?  Is there another option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the CSS files are automatically generated, you can safely just delete the whole directory if you ever want to clean it, and then have Sass regenerate them.

Comment: That is one option... could build that into the deployment process to make it foolproof.

Comment: Actually, I take that back... production wouldn't be a problem as deployment would regenerate all CSS files.  This is just a local problem.  Thinking about writing a rake task to delete and regenerate all CSS.  Either way, thanks for the input!